# Qual é a diferença entre os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) e os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Tags: python, python-3.x

Os dois parecem retornar exatamente o mesmo. Inclusive, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` retorna o mesmo também.

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como você está fazendo as operações, o resultado tem que ser idêntico mesmo. A função `os.path.dirname('file')` retorna o nome do diretório onde está o arquivo, mas esse nome pode ser relativo. Por exemplo, se o arquivo 'file' estiver no diretório atual, essa função retornará uma string vazia.

Por outro lado, a função `os.path.abspath('file')` retorno o nome *absoluto* do diretório. Ou seja, o nome que você efetivamente usa para salvar e abrir arquivos.

Por exemplo, se preciso salvar um dataframe em um arquivo csv no meu diretório atual, eu deveria fazer:

```
df.to_csv(os.path.abspath('file.csv'))
```

Mas não poderia fazer:

```
df.to_csv(os.path.dirname('file.csv'))
```

Agora, quando você pede ao programa para fazer `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('file'))`, você está dizendo para ele, qual o nome do diretório absoluto em que está esse arquivo? Como o nome é absoluto, não existe possibilidade da função dirname retornar o nome relativo. Por outro lado, quando você faz `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('file'))`, você terá como *output* o nome absoluto do diretório, mesmo que o retono da função dirname seja o nome relativo.